# How to embed SWI-Prolog in a Unity3D project

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll, prolog, embed, swi-prolog

I am using [SWI-Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/) within my Unity3D game project via the [SWIPLCS](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/contrib-swiplcs) DLL interface.

However, when I am building my game, I would like to embed SWI-Prolog so that the end-user does not have to install SWI-Prolog in order to run the build.

I have tried moving the SWI-Prolog installation folder to my Unity3D project and indicating the SWI-Prolog /bin path but it does not seem to work. Any idea how I could do it?

Comment: How is this question related to the other [question](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/compiling-swiplcs-with-unity-webgl/3836)? If one has already been resolved then please note that.

Comment: They are not related per se, I have two problems and I don't think solving one will help solve the other, so I made two different questions. As of now, they are not solved.

Comment: Then why two questions on two different sites?

Comment: I thought the other question was more of a SWI-Prolog problem while this one is more general hence the two different sites. I guess they could have been asked on both sites but I did not want to duplicate them. Was I somehow wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong to ask two different questions on two different sites. For any beginner Prolog questions that can be solved with any Prolog asking here is typical. Asking questions such as yours that are specific to a single Prolog should be asked on the forum for the Prolog if one exist. Since you asked one of your two questions at the SWI-Prolog forum it would seem that this one would also be there. In the many years of seeing Prolog questions I have never seen two different questions by the same OP asked at almost the same time on two different forums.